# Copy a dynamic range of values, possibly with the help of Vlookup or Match

Tags: vba, dynamic, copy, range, vlookup

Every year a row of data is added to my work sheet at row 14 (the years are listed in descending order). I'm trying to copy a range that starts at C14 and ends somewhere in column C based on the value '1990' in column A. I thought vlookup may be able to solve this but perhaps not. I'm definitely open to any other methods. Here is the code I was trying to get to work.

```
Sub Figure11()
iRow = Cells(14, 1).End(xlDown).Row
Sheets("BCW").Range("C14:=Vlookup(1990, A14:C" & iRow & ", 3,FALSE)").Copy
Worksheets("Figure1-1").Range("B3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the year 1990 appears only **once** in column A:

```
Sub Figure11()
Dim yr1990 As Variant
Dim rw As Integer

Sheets("BCW").Activate
Set yr1990 = Columns(1).Find(what:=1990, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If yr1990 Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "year 1990 not found"
        Exit Sub
    Else:
        rw = Cells.Find(what:=1990, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    End If
Range("C14", Cells(rw, 3)).Copy
Worksheets("Figure1-1").Range("B3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Anytime! Glad it helps